# How can I find related learndash course id from woocommerce product object?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have woocommerce integrated with LearnDash. Now I am trying to get the selected course (related course) from the woocommerce product object or any other way (by woocommerce product id). There must be a way as buying the product unlocks the course. Just cannot find it.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The related course data is stored as post_meta on the WooCommerce Product.

You can see this in wp-content/plugins/learndash-woocommerce/learndash_woocommerce.php line 150 or so when the render_course_selector() function updates the post meta with '_related_courses' is it's key included in the $_POST on saving the product.

For my use case, I needed to get it in the outgoing emails so I did this:

```
function my_plugin_add_course_link_to_emails($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text)
{
    $html = '<div class="email-course-link">';
    $related_courses = get_post_meta($item->get_product_id(), '_related_course');
    foreach ($related_courses as $related_course) {
        $id = $related_course[0];
        $url = learndash_get_course_url($id);
        $html .= '<a href="' . $url . '">Course Link</a>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'my_plugin_add_course_link_to_emails', 10, 4);
```

The magic line that answers your question though is this one:

```
$related_courses = get_post_meta($item->get_product_id(), '_related_course');
```

Any variation of the above should do the trick for you.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you very much! Only thing I changed is that I added 'true' as attribute on function get_post_meta, to receive single value instead of array.

Comment: Can I get related product based on learndash course id?

Comment: @shenkwen Did you resolved it ? I also want to get product id from course id.